# Error on my Haskell code

Tags: parsing, haskell

I get this error on my code:

"parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)"

```
max3 a b c = if a>b && a>c then show a
     else if b>a && b>c then show b
     else if c>a && c>b then show c
```

i need to get the higher number between a, b and c

EDIT: After adding the else clause as suggested:

```
max3 a b c = if a>b && a>c then show a
     else if b>a && b>c then show b
     else if c>a && c>b then show c
     else show "At least two numbers are the same"
```

now i get this error " parse error on input `if' "

EDITED as suggested!

EDITED: SOLVED, i did with guards like [shree.pat18](/questions/tagged/shree.pat18) said! Ty!

Comment: you need a final "else".  Or you could use `maximum [a,b,c]`

Comment: Actually it is "At least two numbers are the same".

Comment: `otherwise` works with guards, not if...else

Comment: then why i get that parse error on my first case? x_x

Comment: Your current code loads fine for me. Maybe there's something else in your file that causes trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John L mentions in the comments, you need a final `else` clause to catch the case when none of your conditions is true.

Alternatively, you may use guards instead of `if..else if`, like so:

```
max3 a b c 
          | a > b && a > c = show a
          | b > a && b > c = show b
          | c > a && c > b = show c
          | otherwise = show "At least two numbers are the same"
```

Comment: max3 a b c
               if a>b && a>c then show a
               else if b>a && b>c then show b
               else if c>a && c>b then show c
               else show "The numbers are the same"

i added else and now appear this "parse error on input `if'"

Comment: Please add your updated code into your question. Also, did you try my updated code which uses guards?

Comment: The conditions are non-exhaustive. a=b=2, c=1. Always use `otherwise`.

Comment: i used otherwise and i still get error "parse error on input `if'"

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.List (maximum)

max3 a b c = maximum [a, b, c]
```

Fuhgeddaboudit.

Comment: i need to create the function, its an exercise that need to my class!

Comment: But, you *did* create the function.  Why can you use `show`, `&&`, and `>`, all defined by the standard library (not the language) but you can't use `maximum` also defined by the standard library?